# Ubuntu desktop 16.10 - No network inside terminal

Tags: networking, dns

Lately I've been having a weird problem on my Ubuntu 16.10 desktop.
When i'm inside the terminal, networking doesn't work, i can't install packages and i can't run software that requires networking from the terminal.

The strange thing is that everything besides the terminal like the browsers work fine.

When i type "curl google.com" it says that it couldn't resolve host: google.com

I think it's a DNS problem because when i work directly with IP addresses, curl works.
I tried to modify my /etc/resolv.conf file and add the google dns server but it doesn't work either, restarting the networking service or rebooting the system doesn't work either. I'm left out of options.

Please help,
Thank you.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @SahilArora Non that i'm aware of..

Comment: Go to your browser's network settings and check if it's working behind a proxy. If yes, then you need to set proxy in terminal. Also check if you have a custom DNS in the network you are connected to.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved,

1. I removed all the interfaces from /etc/network/interfaces so that
   they won't conflict with the interfaces that are defined in the
   NetworkManager service.
2. I modified /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base and added Google's nameservers
   (8.8.4.4 and 8.8.8.8) and then rebooted.

Now everything works fine.